# Folland pre-meausre for product measure is a pre-measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Let $(X, \mathcal{X}, \mu)$ and $(Y, N, v)$ be measure spaces. We have already discussed, product $\sigma$ algebra $\mathcal{N} \otimes \mathcal{N}$ on $X \times Y$; we now construct a measure on $\mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}$ thaf in an obvious sense, the product of $\mu$ and $\nu$.
>
> To begin with, we define a (measurable) rectangle to be a set of the form $A x$, where $A \in \mathcal{M}$ and $B \in \mathcal{N}$. Clearly
> $(A \times B) \cap(E \times F)=(A \cap E) \times(B \cap F), \quad(A \times B)^c=\left(X \times B^{c}\right) \cup\left(A^{c} \times B\right)$ Therefore, by Proposition 1.7, the collection $\mathcal{A}$ of finite disjoint unions of rectangls is an algebra, and of course the $\sigma$-algebra it generates is $\mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}$.
>
> Suppose $A \times B$ is a rectangle that is a (finite or countable) disjoint union y rectangles $A_j \times B_j$. Then for $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$.
> $$
> \chi_A(x) \chi B(y)=\chi_{A \times B}(x, y)=\sum \chi_A, \times B_1(x, y)=\sum \chi_A,(x) \chi_B,(y) .
> $$
> If we integrate with respect to $x$ and use Theorem $2.15$, we obtain
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \mu(A) \chi_B(y)=\int \chi_A(x) \chi_B(y) d \mu(x) &=\sum \int \chi_{A_1}(x) \chi_{B_j}(y) d \mu(x) \\
> &=\sum \mu\left(A_j\right) \chi_{B_j}(y) .
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> In the same way, integration in $y$ then yields
> $$
> \mu(A) \nu(B)=\sum \mu\left(A_j\right) \nu\left(B_j\right) .
> $$
> It follows that if $E \in A$ is the disjoint union of rectangles $A_1 \times B_1, \ldots, A_n \times B_n$, and we set
> $$
> \pi(E)=\sum_1^n \mu\left(A_j\right) \nu\left(B_j\right)
> $$
> (with the usual convention that $0 \cdot \infty=0$ ), then $\pi$ is well defined on $\mathcal{A}$ (since any two representations of $E$ as a finite disjoint union of rectangles have a common refinement), and $\pi$ is a premeasure on $\mathcal{A}$. According to Theorem $1.14$, therefore, $\pi$ generates an outer measure on $X \times Y$ whose restriction to $\mathcal{M}^{\prime} \otimes \mathcal{N}$ is a measure that extends $\pi$. Wo call this measure the product of $\mu$ and $\nu$ and denote it by $\mu \times \nu$. Moreover, if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are $\sigma$-finite - say, $X=\bigcup_1^{\infty} A_j$ and $Y=\bigcup_1^{\infty} B_k$ with $\mu\left(A_j\right)<$ $\infty$ and $\nu\left(B_k\right)<\infty$ - then $X \times Y=\bigcup_{j, k} A_j \times B_k$, and $\mu \times \nu\left(A_j \times B_k\right)<\infty$, so $\mu \times \nu$ is also $\sigma$-finite. In this case, by Theorem $1.14, \mu \times \nu$ is the unique measure on $\mathcal{N} \otimes \mathcal{N}$ such that $\mu \times \nu(A \times B)=\mu(A) \nu(B)$ for all rectangles $A \times B$.

Why is it that $\pi$ is a pre-measure? It seems we have only defined it for finite disjoint unions of rectangles. To show $\pi$ is a pre-measure, I need to show that for $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n_j}A_i^j\times B_i^j \in \mathcal{A}$, disjoint, then

$$\pi(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty \bigcup_{i=1}^{n_j}A_i^j\times B_i^j) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty\pi(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n_j}A_i^j\times B_i^j)$$

but I am not sure how to show this holds, as we have not defined it for sets which are not finite unions of rectangles.

Comment: You only need to consider pairwise disjoint sequences of boxes $E_n=A_n\times B_n$. Then for any $y\in Y$, $(E^y_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ is a disjoint sequence of sets in $\mathcal{X}$ (similarly, for any $x\in X$, $((E_n)_x:n\in\mathbb{N})$ is a sequence of disjoint sequences in $Y$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz But we have only defined this function $\pi$ for finite disjoint unions of measurable rectangles. If we are to show this for countable disjoint unions, how is the function still defined?

Comment: You consider a finite union of rectangles and assume that this finite union of rectangles is expressed as a possibly infinite disjoint union of finite unions of rectangles. Then you need to show that the measures sum up. Everything is defined since you assume that the infinite union is actually also a finite union (this is not used in the proof, however).

Answer (score 2):

Since $E_j\in \mathcal{A}$, $E_j$ is a finite disjoint union of rectangles;

$$E_j=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n_j} A_i^j \times B_i^j$$

by the definition of $\pi$;

$$\pi(E_j)=\sum_{i=1}^{n_j}\mu(A_i^j) v(B_i^j)$$

Since $$\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}E_j\in \mathcal{A}$$

$\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}E_j$ is a finite disjoint union of rectangles;

$$\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}E_j=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{i=1}^{n_j}A_i^j\times B_i^j=\bigcup_{k=1}^NA_k\times B_k$$

so

$$\pi\left (\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}E_j \right )=\sum_{k=1}^N \mu(A_k) v(B_k)$$

Similar to the derivation in the text using $\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{i=1}^{n_j}A_i^j\times B_i^j=\bigcup_{k=1}^NA_k\times B_k$

$$\begin{aligned}\sum_{k=1}^N \chi_{A_k}(x) \chi_{B_k}(y)&=\sum_{k=1}^N \chi_{A_k\times B_k} (x,y)\\&= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n_j} \chi_{A_i^j \times B_i^j}(x,y)\\ &= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n_j} \chi_{A_i^j}(x)\chi_{B_i^j}(y)\end{aligned}$$

then integrating both sides of the above equation first wrt $x$ and then wrt $y$ we get;

$$\sum_{k=1}^N \mu(A_k) v(B_k)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n_j}\mu(A_i^j) v(B_i^j)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \pi(E_j)$$

therefore

$$\pi\left (\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}E_j \right )=\sum_{k=1}^N \mu(A_k) v(B_k)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \pi(E_j)$$

It follows that $\pi$ is a premeasure.